# Show textView after interval of 1 second

Tags: android, textview

I am new in Android . I am creating a quiz based app in which I have to show questions and 4 options with interval of .5 second.
For example,question is visible and after .5 sec,option1 is visible and after .5 sec.,option2 is visible and so on..

Comment: search postdelay in android and Welcome to SO!!!

Answer (score 0):

first visibility gone set in xml file

Java file

```
    txtview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            txtview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
    private long time = 0;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
       //settext here
        }
    }, 1000); /

/ delaying 1 second
}
```